# breeze mongo manager.saveChanges() error

Tags: mongodb, breeze, savechanges

I'm learning from [breeze-zza-mongodb](http://www.getbreezenow.com/samples/zza) sample.

I get some problems when i try to use the saveChanges() function from breeze.

This is the error i get:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of null at... node_modules\breeze-mongodb\mongoSaveHandler.js : 229:20 at Array.forEach"

Any of you tried and got this error? I searched Google for a bit longer but i can't find this issue. And if i try to manager.getChanges() and put the changes in array, i get my entity with modified state.

The guys from breeze didn't covered this part and i'm completly blind in this. Thank you for your time guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. I included the modules in VS so i can debug and i noticed that breeze misnamed my collection name for some reason adding an s at the end.
Anyway.. for now i just removed that, and it works. I will dig deeper to see where and why is breeze adding an s at the end of my collection name because i want to treat the cause, not the effect. Thanks.